# struts2 + shiro + spring, why did not call MyRealm's function?

Tags: spring, jsp, struts2, shiro

Recently, I am studying to set up SSH+Shiro environment, and I have some questions when using Shiro.

This is my applicationContent.xml:

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>

    <property name="loginUrl" value="/public/login.jsp" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="/public/index.jsp" />
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/public/error.jsp" />

    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /login = anon
            /** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But in login.jsp when I submit the form, it did not goto index.jsp(login success), And MyRealm::doGetAuthenticationInfo were not called.

This is my login.jsp:

```
<form action="login.action" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

What's the right way to do? Thanks a lot.